# setText within Fragment not updating

Tags: java, android, button, fragment, settext

I am currently attempting to clear the sensor values in a fragment, that are constantly being updated, however the clear button that I have set does nothing, even when I have paused the sensors. 
Have I correctly setup the onViewCreated?

I have also attempted to setup the textviews in onCreateView to no success.
I get no errors whatsoever when I press the clear button, the values just don't clear.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    mPitchView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    mRollView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    mAzimuthView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    view.findViewById(R.id.button_clear).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            onClear();

        }
    });   
}


public void onClear(){


    mPitchView.setText("");
    mRollView.setText("");
    mAzimuthView.setText("");
}
```

Also I have two other buttons start and stop which work perfectly fine.
I think the issue is the textview not updating.

Comment: Log your onclick to see if there is an output in the logcat

Comment: Try initializing `mPitchView`, `mRollView`, etc outside of the onViewCreated method. Also inside of the onClear() method try setting `mPitchView.getText().clear();`

Comment: Honestly, this code looks fine. Are you sure you are using the correct ids for the views?

Comment: Did you try to put a breakpoint on the onClear() method and check if it has been hit?

Comment: @ cole For fragments, i think i have to initialise the views inside the method? Correct me if I'm wrong.
@ cricket yes I am sure.
@ Lichader yes I have tried, the buttons are being hit and method is called.

Comment: this should work since you say onclear gets called. the only reason I can see maybe are altering these values later on onresume or somewhere else?

Comment: @aloupas it shouldn't be , i have tried using onstop and onpause to ensure sensor values are not updated , following with onclear, however text still remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use  Handler     

 Handler txtsettext = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                            txtsettext.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                   mPitchView.setText("");
                                   mRollView.setText("");
                                   mAzimuthView.setText("");   

                                }
                            });
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I am relatively new to the concepts of handlers, how would I incorporate it into my code?

Comment: public void onClear(){


  Handler txtsettext = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                            txtsettext.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                   mPitchView.setText("");
                                   mRollView.setText("");
                                   mAzimuthView.setText("");   

                                }
                            });
}

Comment: Have tried again, works now , turns out there was a runnable causing the display to be constantly updated with the last sensor result. My fault.
Thanks